# Get the value of a TD field when a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I had the following code and the user was to click the delete button, using jQuery, how would I get the name of the group about it (Test Group in the example below)? And in case any one wonders, it's because I want to display a confirmation box with the name of the group that is about to be delete in it.

```
<td class='title column-title'>Test Group
    <div class="row-actions">
        <span class='delete'>
            <a id="single-delete" href="?page=permissions-options-eidtor&action=delete&action_role=test_group&role=&paged=2&message=3">Delete</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#single-delete').click(function() {
   $(this).parents('.column-title').text();
});
```

Comment: Thanks - in conjunction with wrapping my text in a `<label>` tag and ammending your solution to end in `.find('label').text()` I now have this working as I would like.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this;

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#single-delete').click(function() {
     $(this).closest('.column-title').text(""); // UPDATE: Won´t work as text() returns all inner text.
  });

});
```

**UPDATE**

Your link `#single-delete` should have a class but you could also use selector `.delete a` and it would be good to wrap the text with a `span` like this `<span class="label">Test group</span>` or simular.

**UPDATE 2**

```
$('.delete a').click(function(e) {

    var group = $(this).closest('.column-title').find('.label').first().text();
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the group "' + group + '"?');

});
```

Comment: As a rule, if a piece of text is needed within your code, it is a good idea to put it in an html element of some sort, to allow it to be extracted irrespective of what other controls there are.

Comment: Thanks guys - that was a bit of an oversite, the text is now wrapped in `<label>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a dynamic link, i suggest to add a custom attribute to your a-element:

```
<td class='title column-title'>Test Group
    <div class="row-actions">
        <span class='delete'>
            <a id="single-delete" actionrole="test_group" href="...">Delete</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</td>
```

In your confirm you can use:

```
var text = 'Delete group ' + $('#single-delete').attr('actionrole') + '?';
var result = confirm(text);
```

If this is not do able you can extract the href attribute of your link and then extract the parameter with regex.

**Update**

See [this example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wRaPp/)

Comment: I should better read the questions .. the only "test gorup" that i saw was on your href attribute :/ I think my answer will not work for you

Comment: It could work - the links are produced by a `foreach` loop, so I couild add the name of the group under your custom atribute. However, through a combination of help here, I've now got this working as desired. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Matching the `<td>` ancestor and getting its inner [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) won't work as expected, since the value returned will also contain the inner text of all the descendant elements, including the link's.

You can work around that by using [contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/) and [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to isolate the text node children of the `<td>` element, then concatenate their values with [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) and [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
$(".delete a").click(function() {
    var group = $(this).closest(".column-title").contents().filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    }).map(function() {
        return this.nodeValue;
    }).get().join("");

    // Now do something with 'group'...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is meant by 'deleting the group in it', but I can tell how to track the 'test_group' parameter i.e. 'action_role' with the below code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#single-delete').click(function() {
     console.log($(this).attr("href").split('&')[2].split('=')[1]);
  });
 });
</script>
```